# How can I access login user data using external files in joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5

I am having trouble in accessing the data of the login user in joomla site.
Can someone help me on it?

I've tried this code:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', '/' );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS .'xampp' . DS .'UPOnlineLeave '. DS .'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS .'xampp' . DS .'UPOnlineLeave '. DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS .'xampp' . DS .'UPOnlineLeave '. DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    $session =& JFactory::getSession();
$user->username;
```

but it produces `JOSerror:application instantation error`.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Fisrt you need to load the entire Joomla Framework:

```
// Get Joomla! framework
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( '_VALID_MOS', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
```

### Only then you can try to get the user

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the following lines to include the joomla default libraries.

You can also refer the code on the root path of the project `index.php` file

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';
```

Comment: i still got the same error... jos-Error: Application Instantiation Error